# Smooth movement with Geometry Nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, transforms, smooth

I have made a cannon controlled by the geometry nodes.
It has a input value nammed 'moving' that allows:

When equals to 0-> it stays still to the inicial position. Rotation Z = 0.

When equals to 1-> it moves with rotation Z = cosine(#frame/10).

It works fine, the only problems is that when you change the value of 'moving' the movement of the canon is not smooth at all.

**Is there a way, when you switch the value of 'moving', to move the rotation angle in several frames to the desired position to make the movement more smooth?**

[image: Detail Geometry Nodes]

[image: Cannon]

Video of the cannon movement: [Cannon movement](https://youtu.be/l6QzM0fiT6U)

Thanks for you help and time !
:)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a switch node, you could use a mix node like this:

[image]

Change the input value of your node group to float and animate the value smoothly:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: It's a very clean solution and it works fine. The Geometry Nodes code is even easier.
Thanks again Chris ! :D